# count files in directory of specific name

Tags: scala

I have a directory "/usr/local/mod_in/" which is containing many files:

```
03_abc.csv
03_bcd.csv
ela.csv
ghi.csv
```

I need count of files in directory whose name starts with 03_ only.In this case count should be 2 .

I have tried this approach but it's not working :

```
val cntSales= Files.list(Paths.get(parentDir+"/03_*")).count()
```

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `listFiles` of java file API and use `count` from scala std lib.

```
scala> new File("/").listFiles.count(f => f.isFile && f.getName.startsWith("."))
res6: Int = 3
```

In your case

```
new File(complete_path_here).listFiles.count(f => f.isFile && f.getName == file_name_to_match)
```

Note: File extension is also part of file name

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner that takes care of edge conditions and error cases:

```
Option(new java.io.File("your/directory/path/here").list).map(_.count(_.startsWith("03_"))).getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: This is working and  have accepted this answer and voted also .Thanks !!

Comment: Also consider up voting if the solution helped!